# Sending 'Magic Packet' with .vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm a help desk in Japan and although I've been studying Python for my own project, now I need to compose VBScript which broadcast the 'Magic Packet' to 200+ PCs in call centre.

Could somebody please lead me how I can achieve this goal or simply teach me the code?

For example, our company's compliance doesn't allow me to download any free software, but somehow if I could open it and copy the source code with .txt and bring it into the company will be OK....

Or... I found some VB6 script below which I believe is exactly what I need, so maybe someone could translate it into VBS??

```
Dim strIP As String = "192.168.1.1" 'IPアドレス
Dim strMAC As String = "00-00-00-00-00-00" 'マックアドレス

'送信データを作成
Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
Dim sendBytes(0 To 101) As Byte

'最初に&hFFを6個付ける
For I = 1 To 6
    sendBytes(intCounter) = &HFF
    intCounter += 1
Next
'MACアドレスを16回繰り返す
For I = 1 To 16
    'MACアドレス読込み
    For J = 0 To 5
        '16進数を変換して読込み
        sendBytes(intCounter) = Byte.Parse(strMAC.Substring(J * 3, 2), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
        intCounter += 1
    Next
Next

'データを送信するポート番号
Dim RemotePort As Integer = 2304 '何でも良い

'送信先IP指定（ブロードキャストとピンポイントの両方に送信してみる）
Dim BCIP As System.Net.IPAddress
Dim EP As System.Net.IPEndPoint
Dim UDP As New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient'UDP接続

'ブロードキャストアドレス指定で送信するとき
BCIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255")
EP = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(BCIP, RemotePort)
'送信先を指定してデータを送信する
UDP.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, EP)

'ピンポイントのIPアドレス指定して送信するとき
BCIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(strIP)
EP = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(BCIP, RemotePort)
'送信先を指定してデータを送信する
UDP.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, EP)

'UDP接続を終了
udp.Close()
```

I'm aware that this kind of silly open question would irritate some intermediate tech person, so just ignore me if you feel uncomfortable about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have is VB.NET, not VB6 or VBScript. VBScript does not have built-in support for Sockets, nor does Windows come with a COM library for working with sockets, but third-party libraries are available (e.g. from Chilkat): http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/socket_connect.asp

If you're at the sysadmin side of things, you'll be better off using PowerShell:

Here's an example of what you want (sending a magic-packet): http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/1506.aspx

Comment: Thanks Dai! Though the PowerShell aren't the exception I can not use in our office..

Comment: @HiroGotanda An alternative is to simply call a command-line magic-packet program using `WScript.Shell`: e.g. http://www.matcode.com/wol.htm

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks again for you time to advise me on this. Just let me confirm that the suggested website (e.g.matcode.com/wol.htm) is not saying to download MC-WOL.exe for sendign Magic packet with this command?

Comment: @HiroGotanda I don't understand you, sorry.

Comment: That is embarrassing... Sorry me English.. The link you suggested above is using MC-WOL.exe, isn't it? Our company does not allow me to use any free software what so ever...

Comment: @HiroGotanda I'm afraid you're stuck then :(